# Struggling with Callbacks in routes - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

In my nodejs backend i have a route that deletes products. Because users can upload an image associated with a product, the corresponding image needs to be deleted too. But i'm struggling to do this.

My nodejs:

```
productRoutes.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Product.find({_id: id}).select('name').exec().then(product => {
        var name = product[0].name;
        rimraf('uploads/imgs/' + name, function () {
            console.log('uploads/imgs/' + name + ' deleted');
        });
    });
    Product.remove({_id: id})
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

I first search for the product name that has to be deleted. Then i delete its folder with rimraf.

And then the product has to be removed. Now i know i'm doing this wrong because of NodeJS' asinchronity. And there will be an error that the name variable is undefined because NodeJS works asynchronous.

But i'm really struggling to do this the right way. Can you guys help?

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem is. Where do you think you will get the error `name is undefined` in your code?

Comment: var name = product[0].name;

if i console.log(name) it gives undefined because the product is already deleted

Comment: you can check the contents of product by adding a console.log(product)

Answer (score 1):

In such situtations, you can always go with the concept of `Promises` or `async/await`. These concepts came into existence keeping in mind that node.js is *asynchronous* in nature and sometimes, the *synchronous* nature might be required. In cases where the operations you have to perform synchronously are 2 or 3 (better to stick to 2), its fine to use *nested callbacks*. However, more nested callbacks gave rise to the concept of [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). Therefore, your purpose might get fulfilled, but the code is more hideous than ever.

**Best Practices -**

Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) wherever possible -

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Product.find(... goes here.
    /* inside the callback of Product.find, if error is encountered, do - 
       reject(err);
    */
     /* else, if everything works fine - 
        resolve(data);
     */
}).then((data) => {
     // Product.remove goes here
}).catch((err) => {
     // error handling goes here
});
```

You can also use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function to achieve this. The methodology is clearly described in the link I mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier if you use the [`findOneAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandremove_findOneAndRemove) method that combines the document find and removal into a single step:

```
productRoutes.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Product.findOneAndRemove({_id: id}, {select: 'name'}, (err, doc, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });        
        }
        else if (doc) {
            rimraf('uploads/imgs/'+ name, function(){
                console.log('uploads/imgs/'+name + ' deleted');
                res.status(200).json(result);
            });    
        }
        else {
            // Don't forget to handle the "id not found" case
            res.send(404);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks makes it easier:

> after each method call i use callbacks which may be tedious sometimes but it is more readable

**after each method some filtered data is passed let it be *data***

```
Product.find({_id: id},(err,data)=>{
      if(err)throw err;
      else{
          data.select('name',(err,newData)=>{
            if(err)throw err;
            var name= newData[0].name;
            //your product will be the final filtered data 
            //you got the idea further you can proceed 
           }
           )
      }
})
```

I find this easier and maintainable as compared to promises,exec,async await
Just Remember that each method will filter the data, so call the given data specific methods. Hope you got it ,it takes lot of time to write the answer especially if you are new here plz try to understand what i write thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But your code gives an error:

       TypeError: data.select is not a function

Comment: Belive me this method works every time if you still din't got it look here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: the data is the filtered object which is returned after finding the given id